# Second derivative at minimum is $0$ only for polynomials?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, optimization, maxima-minima

If I have a smooth real valued function $f$ with a minimum at $x_M$ and the second derivative is

$$
f''(x_M) = 0
$$

does this mean that $f$ has to be a polynomial? If not can someone give an example?

Comment: Interesting.  I would have **guessed** the opposite, that $f$ can't be a polynomial, since $f(x)$ having a minimum at $(x = x_M)$ requires: [1]$~f'(x_M)=0~$ and [2]$~f''(x_M) > 0$.  I could easily be mistaken; my knowledge of Real Analysis is somewhat superficial.

Comment: $f(x)=\cosh(x^2)$, for example.

Comment: $f(x)=cos(x)-(1-x^2/2)$

Comment: @user10354138 Your comment is misaddressed.  Please delete comment and address it to user3137490.

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry.  Anyway, $f''>0$ is only sufficient, not necessary, for a stationary point to be local minimum.  Here we have $\cosh(x^2)=1+\frac12 x^4+o(x^4)$ so $x=0$ is a local minimum (indeed global minimum).

Comment: @user3137490 why was your last comment addressed to me?

Comment: Thank you all for the examples! And sorry for the wrong addressing, too many users with "userXYZ" names.

Comment: @user10354138 Wouldn't the constraint $f''>0$ be **necessary** for polynomials, which was my point?

Comment: @user2661923 Because you assert $f''>0$ is necessary for minimum.

Comment: @user10354138 Isn't it necessary when $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: @user2661923 No, e.g., $f(x)=1+x^4$ has global (hence also local) minimum at $x=0$ and $f''(0)=0$.

Comment: @user10354138 Got it, learned something new - thanks.